# Retrieve array of tuples with different number of elements in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following demand: getting the array of tuples from the first array according to the elements’ appearance in the second array:

```
let totals = [| ("old1", "new1"); ("old2", "new2");  ("old3", "new3"); ("old4", "new4")  |]
let changes = [| "new1"; "new4" |]
```

I want to have this:

```
let updates = [| ("old1", "new1"); ("old4", "new4") |]
```

If the both arrays totals and changes have the same length, then I think it is easy:

```
let updates = Array.zip  changes totals
            |> Array.choose(fun (a, B) -> if a = fst(B) then Some (B) else None)
```

Unfortunately, totals and changes have different number of elements; therefore, I can not find an easy way to get the elements I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution posted by *pad* is correct and will work fine for small number of elements in `changes`. However, it iterates over the array `changes` for every element in `total`, so it may be inefficient for large arrays.

As an alternative, you can turn `changes` into an F# `set` type which allows more efficient membership test:

```
// Create set containing 'changes'
let changesSet = Set.ofArray changes

// Filter totals where the second element is in 'changesSet'
totals |> Array.filter (fun (_, v) -> changesSet.Contains(v))

// Same thing using function composition
totals |> Array.filter (snd >> changesSet.Contains)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great code and some good explanations.
However, I don't quite understand ">>" in your second solution.

Comment: @JohnJohn The `>>` operator composes two _functions_. The first function is `snd`, which takes a tuple and returns the second element and the second function `changesSet.Contains` checks whether a given argument is in the set. The result of a composition is a function that takes a tuple and checks if the second element is in the set `changesSet` (and that's exactly what the first version does!)

Answer (score 3):

You should select pairs in `totals` which have second elements occur in `changes`:

```
let updates = 
      totals 
      |> Array.filter (fun (_, x) -> changes |> Array.exists (fun y -> y = x))
```